# How can I solve this fourth-order polynomial equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

How can I solve this problem to get the value of $x$?
$$x^4 - 5x+ 4=0$$

Comment: Try the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and the factor out whatever you can find from it.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in other answers, the rational roots theorem reduces the problem down to a cubic factoring:

$$x^4-5x+4=(x−1)(x^3+x^2+x−4)$$

To factor the cubic, start with the substitution $x=\frac{2\sqrt2}3y-\frac13$.  You should end up with

$$\frac{16\sqrt2}{27}y^3+\frac{4\sqrt2}9y-\frac{115}{27}=0$$

Multiply by $\frac{27}{4\sqrt2}$ on both sides to get

$$4y^3+3y-\frac{115}{4\sqrt2}=0$$

$$4y^3+3y=\frac{115}{4\sqrt2}$$

Recall a hyperbolic trig identity:

$$\sinh(3\operatorname{arcsinh}(y))=4y^3+3y=\frac{115}{4\sqrt2}$$

$$y=\sinh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{115}{4\sqrt2}\right)\right)$$

$$x=\frac{2{\sqrt2}}3y-\frac13=\frac{2{\sqrt2}}3\sinh\left(\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{115}{4\sqrt2}\right)\right)-\frac13\approx1.15091108434$$

That is the second root.  After factoring it out, the two remaining complex roots may be found via quadratic formula.

Alternatively, if one is able to handle complex exponents, the following form is more compact:

$$x=\frac{2{\sqrt2}}3\sinh\left(\frac{2k\pi i}3+\frac13\operatorname{arcsinh}\left(\frac{115}{4\sqrt2}\right)\right)-\frac13\qquad k=0,1,2$$

Comment: I believe you did the substitution $x=\frac{2\sqrt2}3y-\frac13$ to get coefficients of a cubic something like $4y^3 + 3y$. But how did you reverse engineer the substitution from only the coefficients of $y^3$ and $y$? Because, currently the substitution ($x=\frac{2\sqrt2}3y-\frac13$), atleast to me seems an ingenuity without any supporting argument.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre Practice, you always know the substitution is of the form $x=ay+b$, where the result has $0$ for the coefficient of the $y^2$ term and the ratio of the $y^3$ and $y$ term is $4:3$ ratio.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre Oh, btw, if you take the definitions of $\sinh$ and do some manipulation, it ends up as Pedro's form

Answer (score 1):

Following @GitGud 's idea and using rational root theorem, I found out that $x=1$ is a root of the equation. Hence,
$$\left(x-1\right)\left(x^3+x^2+x-4\right)=0$$
So one solution is $x=1$ and the cubic factor does not have a pretty solution.

Edit:

[image: plot]

The plot of the function shows only $2$ real roots. The second one is also close to $1$.

Comment: The second is $\frac{1}{6} \left(-2 - 4 \sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{115 + 3\sqrt{1473}}} + 2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{115 + 3 \sqrt{1473}}\right)\cong1.1509$.

Comment: Can you share how you calculated it?

Comment: [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4-5x%2B4%3D0) gives the said value.

Comment: Can be approximated by Newton's method, it converges quite quickly: $x_{n+1} =(2x_n^3+x_n^2+4)/(3x_n^2+2x_n+1)$ and $x_0=1$ gives $x_1\approx 1.166666667$, $x_2\approx 1.151061174$,  $x_3\approx 1.150911098$,$\dots$

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre Look up methods to find the roots of cubic polynomials.  I have a different form of the root in my answer below :D